# ViewController property not working in root component

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting below error while trying to dismiss modalCtrl using viewCtrl in root component

```
MyApp_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined
```

/*****app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import {ModalController, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      @ViewChild('ViewController') viewCtrl: ViewController;

      constructor() {

        this.initializeApp();

      }

      initializeApp() {

        let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(HomePage);
        profileModal.present();
         setTimeout(function() {
            this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
          }, 2000);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.

1. Place your timeout and dismiss inside the modal (HomePage).
   Example

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      }, 2000);
  }
```

2. Use the dismiss on the `overlay` of your modal.
   Example

```
     let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(HomePage);
     modal.present();
     setTimeout(function() {
         modal.overlay.dismiss();
     }, 2000);
```